# Simple Javascript Sprite Animation - line flicker, but only on iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, animation, sprite

There is a problem with the sprite animation on the homepage of one of my clients, but it only appears when the site is viewed on an iOS device, namely an iPhone or iPad.  I can't replicate the problem on any other device or emulator, so I'm having an issue troubleshooting it (don't own an iPhone or iPad).  The problem is: what looks to be a 1px line is appearing on the right edge of the animation frame pretty much all the time, and a similar line flickers occasionally at the top of the frame as the animation runs.  The animation itself is a simple javascript sprite sheet animation.  I'm operating under the assumption that I have the sprite animation programmed correctly since it appears correctly on every other device, platform and browser I've checked.  It even works in IE.

Two questions:

1. What would cause a simple sprite animation to display differently when rendered by iOS?
2. As a small business consultant, I don't have the time and my clients don't have the budget for me to physically test on every single device, so I have to rely on emulators.  What other options do I have if the emulators don't properly demonstrate what the device will display?

I'm not entirely sure of the protocol regarding posting a link to my client's production website, but happy to send a link to anyone willing to help that responds and/or messages me.

Comment: Please add the link to your question and/or post relevant code. As for the second point, usually one iOS and one Android device is enough to test all platforms, otherwise you need to rely on screenshots and customer feedback.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO.

I spend a lot of time working specifically with iOS on the web and have run into similar situations. Without tweaking an example you post I won't be able to prove it exactly, but this should at least give you direction.

1. Flickering or semi opaque lines are often caused by the scaling set to the asset. In the world of high DPI displays and fluid layouts, there are differences in rounding that result in fine lines, shimmers, et al. Is there any scaling set on the assets, e.g. background-size, downsampling?
2. The emulators are displaying the software correctly - these issues are a result of hardware. Best thing you can do is buy a flagship for all of the platforms you test on, or look into local resources like [Clearleft's Device Testing Lab](http://clearleft.com/testlab/)

Comment: 1. I have the animation div/frame set to a fixed size, specifically to avoid the types of scaling issues I encountered when I first started programming the animation.  The only dynamic part of the page is the auto-margin set on the container.  What confuses me is that the same flicker appears whether the page is viewed on an iPhone5 or a retina iPad, but I can't get it to appear anywhere else, even emulating on a MacBook.

Even with access to a device to discover this type of problem, how do I diagnose what is causing it to fix the problem if it isn't bad code?

Comment: The container's fixed size is the issue and it's only apparent on Retina screens (5/iPad) because they're rendering the div with subpixel antialiasing. Try making a full-width version or cropping into the animated element by a pixel or so (margin: -1px; on child, overflow: hidden; on parent.

Comment: @MatthewWren Checked out the site (Maggin). Another possible cause is that you have the viewport zoomed instead of natural resolution. In a way, you're scaling the viewport, scaling the graphic, and then it's rendered with antialiasing. Recreating the same page with a proper device-width value will help a lot, but that's a mobile layout.

Comment: So you're saying adding  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> should remove the line, correct?  it's the scaling causing the line to appear and removing it should remove the line?

Comment: @MatthewWren Yes, that will be a good start because the browser won't be zooming out to fit desktop size content onto the display. But... that's also opening the door to a proper mobile site, which is a different game altogether.

Comment: didn't fix it, not sure what else to try